# Add custom test source folders to eclips project view

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm building an application using Maven for a school project.
I am using Eclipse as IDE.

I have multiple test source folders under:

```
src/test/java  for Unit Tests
src/it/java    for Integration Tests
src/e2e/java   for End-to-End Tests
```

The issue I am having is that:

When I clone the github repository and I import the Maven project in Eclipse, I have to manually add the src/it/java and src/e2e/java to the classpath in order to display them.
Since Gradle shows those folders automatically, is there any way to achieve this in Maven?

I will provide some screenshots for a better understanding.

Thanks to all who will answer :)

**This is what i get when I import the Maven project**

[image: This is what i get when I import the Maven project]]

**I need to manually do this while (e.g.) Gradle automatically shows them**

[image: I need to manually do this while (e.g.) Gradle automatically shows them]]

**This is what I want to get in an automated manner when I import the Maven project**

[image: This is what I want to get in an automated manner when I import the Maven project]]

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your maven project to Gradle project, that may help you.

so you can try to convert your maven project to gradle, and gradle will create all required folder structures

have a look to this link; 
https://howtodoinjava.com/gradle/convert-maven-project-to-gradle-project/

or you may try this update the existing maven project

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not what I'm looking for. I mandatorily need a Maven project :(

Comment: okay then you can try to configure maven project to maven project again